# Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly XAMPP

Tags: mysql, xampp

Cuando abro XAMPP y doy click en Start MySQL me da el siguiente error, a pesar de que antes funcionaba correctamente

> 03:17:20 p.m.  [mysql]    Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
>
> 03:17:20 p.m.  [mysql]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,
>
> 03:17:20 p.m.  [mysql]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
>
> 03:17:20 p.m.  [mysql]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
>
> 03:17:20 p.m.  [mysql]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
>
> 03:17:20 p.m.  [mysql]    If you need more help, copy and post this
>
> 03:17:20 p.m.  [mysql]    entire log window on the forums

El error que aparece en logs es el siguiente:

> 2017-06-05 16:46:03 92c InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
>
> 2017-06-05 16:46:03 2348 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
>
> 2017-06-05 16:46:03 2348 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
>
> 2017-06-05 16:46:03 2348 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
>
> 2017-06-05 16:46:03 2348 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
>
> 2017-06-05 16:46:03 2348 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
>
> 2017-06-05 16:46:03 2348 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
>
> 2017-06-05 16:46:03 2348 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
>
> 2017-06-05 16:46:03 2348 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
>
> 2017-06-05 16:46:03 2348 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring page 0 of tablespace 0
>
> 2017-06-05 16:46:03 2348 [Warning] InnoDB: Doublewrite does not have page_no=0 of space: 0
>
> 2017-06-05 16:46:03 2348 [ERROR] InnoDB: space header page consists of zero bytes in data file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1
>
> 2017-06-05 16:46:03 2348 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not open or create the system tablespace. If you tried to add new data files to the system tablespace, and it failed here, you should now edit innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back to what it was, and remove the new ibdata files InnoDB created in this failed attempt. InnoDB only wrote those files full of zeros, but did not yet use them in any way. But be careful: do not remove old data files which contain your precious data!
>
> 2017-06-05 16:46:03 2348 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
>
> 2017-06-05 16:46:03 2348 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
>
> 2017-06-05 16:46:03 2348 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
>
> 2017-06-05 16:46:03 2348 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
>
> 2017-06-05 16:46:03 2348 [ERROR] Aborting

Ya intente darle solución borrando el archivo`ibdata 1` y cambie los puertos por 8080 pero nada de esto funciona.

Alguien que pueda auxiliarme?

Comment: Algunas veces se ha solucionado siguiendo estos pasos: 1. Salir de XAMPP (pon el puerto como estaba antes, pues dices haberlo cambiado). 2. Ir a `C:\xampp\mysql\directorio data (como se llame)`
 y borrar el archivo  `ibdata1` 3. Reiniciar el equipo.

Answer (score 2):

Al parecer, la mejor opción es reinstalar XAMPP. Han vuelto a preguntar cómo se solucionaba y ésta ha sido la solución final, reinstalar.
Dejo enlace al post.

[Problema con apache en XAMPP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/108308/error-al-iniciar-apache-xampp/108310#108310)

Answer (score 0):

https://youtu.be/5cCT1ThLqqU     este video me solucione el mismo problema

Comment: Hola Ana, bienvenida y gracias por tu colaboración, la respuesta debe ser autocontenida, esto es que no dependa de imágenes o enlaces, por favor, edita la tuya, así evitarás recibir votos negativos y lograrás que tu respuesta sea mejor recibida, gracias. ver [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para evitar votos negativos y/o que tu repuesta sea eliminada. aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.