# Error al iniciar apache "Xampp"

Tags: apache, xampp

Buenos días, tengo instalado el entorno de trabajo xampp en mi pc, y hasta hoy había trabajado bien, pero cuando intente iniciar el servidor apache me aparece este error:

```
Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
If you need more help, copy and post this
entire log window on the forums.
```

He cambiado el puerto en los archivos de configuración, sin conseguir solucionar este problema. Agradezco a quien pueda ayudarme a solucionar este problema...

Comment: Estas usando skype al mismo tiempo que usas xampp ? el te esta diciendo que tienes un error en el puerto que usa apache

Comment: No. ni siquiera tengo instalado skype, es más no he instalado nada nuevo en mi pc ya hace un tiempo y como digo hasta hoy empezo a fallar, porque estaba trabajando bien

Comment: Y ya intentaste simplemente cambiando el puerto?

Comment: Sí, le cambié el puerto en httpd.conf y httpd-ssl.conf

Answer (score 1):

No puedes tener instalado MySQL de manera alternativa a XAMPP ni a WAMP, aunque dices que ha sido de repente. Los problemas también ocurren creo que con Skype si se usa a la vez. Primero arranca XAMPP y luego Skype.

Si no has tocado nada, reinstala XAMPP o desinstala e instala WAMP, que da muchos menos conflictos(en caso de que no uses Perl).

Comment: Si fue algo de un día a otro y no entiendo porque... Y pues si tengo contemplado reinstalar pero me gustaría saber si existe una solución para este problema

Comment: Supongo que habrás probado reiniciando, no ? Inicia manualmente Apache, que se puede hacer también por consola. En la página de Apache tienes la documentación técnica.

Hay otra pregunta en el foro igual que dice lo siguiente:

" Algunas veces se ha solucionado siguiendo estos pasos: 
1. Salir de XAMPP (pon el puerto como estaba antes, pues dices haberlo cambiado). 
2. Ir a **C:\xampp\mysql\directorio data** (como se llame) y borrar el archivo **ibdata1** 
3. Reiniciar el equipo. "

Comment: Si ya he reiniciado y dejado el puerto por defecto...

Comment: Lo que si no he probado aún es: 2. Ir a C:\xampp\mysql\directorio data (como se llame) y borrar el archivo ibdata1 3. Reiniciar el equipo. " así que lo voy a hacer y veremos...

Answer (score 1):

Agradezco a todos por su ayuda. Aunque la solución fue reinstalar xampp, nuevamente gracias por su ayuda...